# for loop containing all equals statements C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to understand a coding example I found in C, and one of the for loops is structured like this:

```
for(int x=0; int y=0; int z!=0){some code}
```

I am used to seeing something more like this:

```
for(int x=0; x < someLimit; x++){some code}
```

What does the mystery for loop do exactly?

Comment: Compile and you will understand that these are ....

Comment: Not sure where you found that, but there's no mystery; that's not a valid for-loop.

Comment: Maybe you saw this? `for(int x=0,y=0,z=1;z!=0;){code}`

Comment: https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/09/round-robin-scheduling-program-in-c.html  I found it here, line 19.  What's with the downvote?

Comment: Then put the exact statement here..you have copied it wrong way.

Comment: aha indeed I have done a typo.  still though, no iterator at the end of the for conditions?  didn't know that.

Comment: What will you do if you end up seeing this: `for(; ;){some code}`

Comment: There are 8 kinds of for loop you can see `for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++),
for(; i< 10; i++),
for(;; i++),
for(;;),
for(int i = 0; ; i++),
for(int i = 0; ;),
for(int i = 0; i< 10; ),
for(; i< 10;)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copied the statement wrong. In the program you cited in your comment there's only one `for` statement which approximates what you posted above:

```
for(time=0,count=0;remain!=0;)
```

In this case the "initialization" portion of the `for` statement is

```
time=0,count=0
```

Note that the character between the initialization of time and count is a comma, not a semicolon. This means 
that both `time` and `count` are set to zero. The "test" portion of the `for` statement is

```
remain != 0
```

meaning that the loop will continue as long as `remain` is not equal to zero.

In this `for` statement the "increment" portion is empty - so nothing is incremented/decremented/whatever at the end of each pass through the loop.

Best of luck.

Answer (score -2):

In for loop you can omit initialization part(provided you initialized your variable before) and increment/decrement part. you can have also multiple initialization like in your example x=0;y=0 and multiple increment/decrement. in your first example for loop have multiple initialization for x and y and no increment/decrement part. and z part is the condition. Please check why you are declaring z there. I am not sure about that. It would be better if you will upload full code of that example.

Comment: In this case it's the increment portion which was omitted.